# Why does the debugger have to jump "back and forth" before it sets my tuple value?

Tags: macos, debugging, swift, tuples, xcode6

I've actually fixed this problem already (while documenting it for this post), but I still want to know is why it is happening, so that I can understand what I did and hopefully avoid wasting time with it in the future.

In a Swift project, I have a function that parses out a string that I know will be presented in a specific format and uses it to fill in some instance variables.

There is a helper function that is passed the string, a starting index, and a divider character and spits out a tuple made up of the next string and the index from which to continue. Just in case a poorly formatted string gets passed in, I define a return type of (String, Int)? and return nil if the divider character isn't found.

The helper function looks, in relevant part, like this:

```
   func nextChunk(stringArray: Array<Character>, startIndex: Int, divider: Character) -> (String, Int)?
    {

    [...]

 var returnValue: (String, Int)? = (returnString, i)
        return returnValue
    }
```

So far, so good. I set a breakpoint, and just before the function returns, I see that all is as it should be:

```
(lldb) po returnValue
(0 = "21三體綜合症", 1 = 7)
 {
  0 = "21三體綜合症"
  1 = 7
}
```

That's what I expected to see: the correct string value, and the correct index.

However, when I go back to the init() function that called the helper in the first place, and put a breakpoint immediately after the call:

```
var returnedValue = self.nextChunk(stringArray, startIndex: stringArrayIndex, divider: " ")
```

I get a completely different value for returnedValue than I had for returnValue:

```
(lldb) po returnedValue
(0 = "I", 1 = 48)
 {
  0 = "I"
  1 = 48
}
```

Now here's the *really* weird part. After I get the return value, I want to test to see if it's nil, and if it's not, I want to use the values I fetched to set a couple of instance variables:

```
    if(returnedValue == nil)
    {
        return
    }
    else
    {
        self.traditionalCharacter = returnedValue!.0
        stringArrayIndex = returnedValue!.1
    }
```

If I comment out both of the lines in the "else" brackets:

```
    else
    {
        // self.traditionalCharacter = returnedValue!.0
        // stringArrayIndex = returnedValue!.1
    }
```

then my original breakpoint gives the expected value for the returned tuple:

```
(lldb) po returnedValue
(0 = "21三體綜合症", 1 = 7)
 {
  0 = "21三體綜合症"
  1 = 7
}
```

Again: the breakpoint is set *before* this if/else statement, so I'm taking the value before any of this code has had the chance to execute.

After banging my head against this for a few hours, I realize that...there isn't actually a problem. If I press the "step over" button in the debugger, the execution pointer jumps back from the if() line to the call to nextChunk. Pressing it again sends it forward to "if" again, and sets the values properly.

This extra double-jump only happens if the assignment code is active, consistently and reproducibly. As I know, since I reproduced it for hours trying to figure out what was wrong before even trying stepping forward and noticing that it "fixed itself."

So my question is: why? Is this a bug in the debugger, or am I using breakpoints wrong? It happens just the same whether I put the breakpoint between the function call and the if() or on the if() line. Can someone explain why the debugger is jumping back and forth and when the value I need is actually getting set?

Comment: compiler may reorder your code as an optimization